# Compactness result by slicing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am now consider $\Omega=I\times J\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, where $I$ and $J$ are two open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. For all $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $x=(y,z)\in I\times J$, I write
$$u^y(z)=u(y,z)\mbox{ for a.e. }y\in I\mbox{ and }u^z(y)=u(y,z)\mbox{ for a.e. }z\in J.$$
I call this one-dimensional slicing of $u$.
Then consider a sequence $(u_n)\subset L^1(\Omega)$, I want to prove two compactness result by slicing.
Part1. Assume that $(u_{n}^{y})$ is convergent in $L^1(J)$ for a.e. $y\in I$ and $(u_n^z)$ is convergent in $L^1(I)$ for a.e. $z\in J$, then $u_n$ is convergent in $L^1(\Omega)$.
My thought is that assume $u_n^y\to u^y\in L^1(J)$ for a.e. $y\in I$ and $u_n^z\to u^z$ for a.e. $z\in J$. Then consider $u=\frac{1}{2}(u^y+u^z)$, I want to show that $u_n\to u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$, but I trap in the very first step that I can not prove my $u$ is indeed a $L^1$ function. But if I just assume $u$ is $L^1$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{I\times J}|u_n-u|&\leq \frac{1}{2}[\int_{I\times J}|u_n-u^y|+|u_n-u^z|]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[\int_{I}\int_{J}|u_n^y-u^y|+\int_{J}\int_{I}|u_n^z-u^z|]\\
\end{align*}
I want to apply the dominated convergence theorem to deduce the convergence in the last line but it seems like to have the same problem as proving $u$ is $L^1$ i.e. I can not find a upper bound.
So can someone help me with this?
Part2. And I also have a more general statement of the compactness theorem: we say a sequence $(\bar{u}_n)$ is $\delta-$close to $(u_n)$ if $\lVert u_n-\bar{u}_n\rVert_1<\delta$ for every $n$.
Assume that for every $\delta>0$ there exist sequence $u_{\delta,n}$ and $\hat{u}_{\delta,n}$ which are $\delta-$close to $(u_n)$ and $(u_{\delta,n}^y)$ is convergent in $L^1(J)$ for a.e. $y\in I$ and $\hat{u}_{\delta,n}^z$ is convergent in $L^1(I)$ for a.e. $z\in J$, then $(u_n)$ is convergent in $L^1(\Omega)$.
I think this proof maybe need the result from part1 and since I have not proved part1, so I do not have any idea now. Can someone maybe help?